# how to make an android app that downloads dynamic forms from mysql database and uploading them the record after filling them?

Tags: android, mysql

im making an android-based data collection app similar to ODKcollect as a college project and im not that good so..

1-how to make a web service and connect my app to mysql database and which language is better for a web-service (PS:my data maycontain images)

2-how to make dynamic form templates then retrieving them from database and making them in the android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php for that, You can write a php script that retrieve values from Mysql Database and then decode them to **JSON** and parse them to the android app. and another script to make the vice-versa Take a **JSON** response from your app and insert it into the Database.
There was a course in udemy that achieves such pattern you might want to [check it](https://www.udemy.com/android-development-course/)